# Javascript beginner : about code syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am new to javascript and i would like to know what is this called in javascript when you have 'data' and then a function after it or a console log?
i would like to know where can i learn more about such syntax?

```
var video = bebop.getVideoStream();
video.on('data', function (data) {

});
```

THANKS

Comment: It's known as a *callback*

Comment: Go learn. It's free --> https://www.codecademy.com/learn/javascript

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works on callbacks.

Whenever data arrives your function passed in second parameter is called.

[check here for callbacks](https://github.com/maxogden/art-of-node/blob/master/readme.md#callbacks)